# Sine wave function as an input value?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

It is possible to use the variable `#frame` in an input field to make the value increment with each frame. It behaves as a Driver.

Example:

[image: Pound sign "frame" input]

We can also halve or double the rate using `#frame/2` or `#frame*2` respectively. So I got to wondering to what extent we can write expressions in input fields. How complex can we get?

Is it also possible to input a sine wave as an expression?

The purpose would be for quickly animating objects that move cyclically:

[image: A pendulum oscillating in a sine wave]

Comment: That thing is hypnotic.  I am getting sleepy, sleepy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, why not. The `#` symbol in the input field tells blender that you are inserting scripted driver with no variables. Everything after `#` will be put into the driver's expression field.

You can get a list what functions are build-in by typing `bpy.app.driver_namespace['` into the console and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can totally input `#cos(frame*pi/20)` to match the curve you provided in the question.

Comment: You can add your own item to the driver namespace `bpy.app.driver_namespace["foo"] = bar`,  foo is how you reference it in a driver expression. `foo / 2` `foo(frame)` `sin(foo)` etc.   The driver expression must have a return value of type float or int

Comment: Excellent! This is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Mentalist Another handy tip is passing the locals() dictionary via  a driver expression eg `foo(locals())`  locals() is a  key, value dictionary, eg if driver has one variable `var` with a value of 1.4 the locals dictionary will be `{"var":1.4}`