# How to create Sine "Pulse" with math nodes and "From/To" inputs Amplitude?

Tags: node-editor, procedural, mathematics

Based on this answer:[Sine wave using only Math nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45537/sine-wave-using-only-math-nodes)

I have the ability to create an animated waveform with an amplitude from 0 to 1.

Very interesting and useful.

But now I would like to ask the more complex question:

How to change the Minimum and Maximum values of Amplitude with the input values of a group node?

It sounded easy, but math isn't my forte, and I'm getting lost in my problem with it.

For example I would like to set from 0.1 to 0.9 or, do from 2.5 to 100.

I don't know if there is something universal Formula, my idea is that it exists, but I am not able to correctly analyze the formulas present on the internet, as my mathematics is very limited

[image]

Comment: I don't know any "Sine Pulse". But if you are talking about waveforms, do you mean a [Pulse Wave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave)? Would your input values then be the pulse width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do I understand it correctly that you want to convert the standard sine wave with an amplitude going from -1 to 1 to something else like going from 0.1 to 0.9 or 2.5 to 100?

Why not simply use a *Map Range* node after the *Sine* node? Since we know the output values of the *Sine* node are *From Min* = -1 and *From Max* = 1, just set the other values accordingly to your desired target range, for example *To Min* = 0.1 and *To Max* = 0.9 as in the following screenshot:

[image: map range for sine]

Of course, if you would want this inside the *Group Node*, you would maybe again place a *Multiply* node before the *Sine* which combines the *Speed* group input with the driver value and connect the *From* group input to the *To Min* input of the *Map Range* as well as the *To* group input to the *To Max* input.

If this isn't what you want you might have to explain a little more what you're aiming for.

For the mathematical background, the group in your screenshot is doing something like the *Map Range*, just split up in single functions. To make the *Map Range* conversion of sine from the -1 to 1 range to a different one just with math nodes, you can make the following considerations and computations (forgive me my quite arbitrary variables):

The peak-to-peak-amplitude of the sine function is:

$$sin_{amp}=sin_{max}-sin_{min}= 1-(-1)=1+1=2$$

The peak-to-peak-amplitude of the target range is:

$$t_{amp}=t_{max}-t_{min}= 0.9-0.1=0.8$$

The ratio between those two amplitudes is:

$$R_{t,sin}=\frac{t_{amp}}{sin_{amp}}=0.4$$

The proportional shift from the initial sine minimum to the target minimum (this works if you replace the minima with the maxima as well):

$$S_{t,sin}=t_{min}\cdot\frac{sin_{amp}}{t_{amp}}-sin_{min}=0.1\cdot\frac{2}{0.8}-(-1)=0.25+1=1.25$$

So you get the final formula to map the sine function from [-1, 1] to [0.1, 0.9] if you add the proportional shift to the result of the sine function and multiply it by the amplitude ratio:

$$(sin(x)+S_{t,sin})\cdot R_{t,sin}=(sin(x)+1.25)\cdot0.4$$

And to not have to calculate everything over and over again, this is a node setup for these equations... by the way, if you input any other value instead of a sine function and exchange the s_min and s_max values for any other range, they would resemble the *To Min* and *To Max* of the *Map Range* node and the result of the node tree would work like the *Map Range* node set to *Linear* with *Clamp* disabled.

[image: map range with functions]

Comment: Hey Gordon this answer is very brilliant and works great. It would also be nice to learn some math, but I think this is what I was looking for with very little effort. You saved me a lot of headaches 

Comment: @NoobCat Wait a few minutes, I'm working on the maths ;)

Comment: @NoobCat I've edited my answer to add some formulas...

Comment: This answer satisfies my question 200% you did a lot more than I was asking. I hope it will be useful to many people.

Answer (score 3):

I understood that you want to create a [pulse wave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave).

[image]

For this you actually only need a rounding up and down of your values.

Since the node `Sinus` always gives you float values between $-1$ and $1$, you can round them up or down to exactly $-1$, $0$ or $1$ with the node `Round`.

The node `Map Range` will then generate the values you need (either in the range $-1$ - $1$, or $0$ - $1$, depending on the values you have reached before).

Additionally you can influence the pulse width of your square wave.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on Gordon's answer, I got what I intended to do. In any case, But this answer is really interesting, a good alternative to what I thought I was doing. A wave like that will be my next goal 