# Animate an object along the z-axis in a sin wave

Tags: animation, drivers, mathematics

So I wanted to make an animation of an object where it bobs up and down along the z-axis, like a sin wave on a graph. [image: Sin Wave]

I understand one way of doing this with drivers, by which I add a driver to the z-axis of the object I want to move and then assign a scale, location or rotation to the empty driving the movement of the object (that was a bit convoluted I know, but it'll be better illustrated by the gif below). [image: current drivers]

Is there a different method that I can use to achieve the same animation, but not require the use of a driver (something that I have to move or scale)? I want to be able to control the intensity of the waves through the use of some simple maths. For example: `Sin(x)` (the red line) and `sin(5x)` (the blue line) have a different frequency in waves. [image: Waves]

I want to be able to control the animation through using similar principles in Blender.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40556/sine-wave-function-as-an-input-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Graph Editor for this by adding *Modifiers*.

Simply add a single keyframe to your object's Z-Coordinate (right-click the property in the Property panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) and select 'Insert Single Keyframe') and then swap to the Graph Editor.

In the Modifiers properties panel add a Built-in Function, select 'Sine', and adjust the properties (Amplitude, Phase Multiplier, etc.).

[image: sine wave]